# Visualizar dados de um banco de dados em modals

Tags: php, sql

Eu fiz uma tabela para apresentar 2 dados do banco de dados, e depois em cada linha metia um icon para que quando clicasse lá aparecia um modal com a informação daquela linha do tipo:

```
<?
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT a.n_processo,a.nome,a.data_nasc,a.cc,g.designacao,a.ciclo_formacao,t.texto
                                    FROM alunos a, cursos g, tipo_curso t
                                    WHERE a.n_curso = g.n_curso
                                    AND g.id_tipo_curso = t.id_tipo_curso");
?>
            <!-- ----------------CABEÇALHO---------------------------- -->
        <table class="tabela1">
        <tr>
            <td id="tb1">Nº Processo</font>
            <td id="tb2">Nome</font>
        </table>

    <?
    //---------------DADOS------------------------
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                {

                    echo "<TABLE class='tabela2'>";
                    echo "<TR class='tabela2'>";
                        echo "<TD  style='padding-left:5px;width:20%;'>".$row['n_processo']."</TD>";
                        echo "<TD style='padding-left:15px;width:55%;'>".$row['nome']."</TD>";
                        echo "<TD style='text-align: right; letter-spacing: 5px; padding-right:10px;'>";

                        // --------------------------------------- MOSTRAR ------------------------------------

                        echo"
                        <button class='menubotao' id='ver'>
                            <i class='fa fa-eye' ></i>
                        </button>

                        echo"

                        <button class='menubotao' id='ver'data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2'>
                            <i class='fa fa-eye' ></i>
                        </button> 

                            <div id='myModal2' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
                              <div class='modal-dialog'>

                                <div class='modal-content' style='letter-spacing:0px; text-align:left;'>
                                  <div class='modal-header' style=' background-color:#0066cc;'>
                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class='modal-title' style='font-size:25px; color:#FFF;'>Dados do Aluno</h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body' style='font-size:20px;'>
                                    <p><b style='background-color:#0066cc;color:white;padding:2px;border-radius:5px;'>Nº de processo:</b> ".$row['n_processo']."</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p><b style='background-color:#0066cc;color:white;padding:2px;border-radius:5px;'>Nome:</b> ".$row['nome']."</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p><b style='background-color:#0066cc;color:white;padding:2px;border-radius:5px;'>Data Nascimento:</b> ".$row['data_nasc']."</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p><b style='background-color:#0066cc;color:white;padding:2px;border-radius:5px;'>C.C. <small>(Cãrtao de Cidadão)</small>:</b> <font style='text-transform:uppercase;'> ".$row['cc']."</font></p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p><b style='background-color:#0066cc;color:white;padding:2px;border-radius:5px;'>Tipo do Curso: </b> ".$row['texto']."</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p><b style='background-color:#0066cc;color:white;padding:2px;border-radius:5px;'>Curso: </b> ".$row['designacao']."</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p><b style='background-color:#0066cc;color:white;padding:2px;border-radius:5px;'>Ciclo de Formação:</b> ".$row['ciclo_formacao']."</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'><i class='fa fa-times fa-2x'></i></button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>
                            ";
```

Quando é clicado no button, aparece um modal com os respetivos dados. No entanto para criar a tabela os dados são apresentados corretamente, mas no quando é clicado no button, qualquer que seja ele, o `value` será sempre da primeira linha. A minha dúvida, é o porque é que isso acontece, sendo que está dentro do `while`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O porque de ser sempre a primeira linha, simples seu `buttom` não cria uma referência para cada modal. **Solução?**

Criar uma variável para iterar a cada ocorrência do `while`. No atributo `data-target` do seu `buttom` acionar ela, e no `id` do modal também.

**Exemplo**

```
//---------------DADOS------------------------
$modal = 0; //variavel para iterar
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   ...
   ...

echo"
    <button class='menubotao' id='ver'data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal".$modal;".'>
      <i class='fa fa-eye' ></i>
    </button>

<div id='myModal".$modal."' class='modal fade' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
...

$modal++;
";
```

*No final do `while` não esquecer de **incrementar** a variável!*

Comment: Obrigado Igor! Ajudou imenso.

Comment: @programmer2016 De nada, estamos aqui para isto!

Answer (score 0):

Observe que existe uma aspas que não foi fechada no código

```
 // --------------------------------------- MOSTRAR ------------------------------------

                    echo"
                    <button class='menubotao' id='ver'>
                        <i class='fa fa-eye' ></i>
                    </button>

                    echo"
```

Digite da seguinte maneira:

```
 // --------------------------------------- MOSTRAR ------------------------------------

                    echo"
                    <button class='menubotao' id='ver'>
                        <i class='fa fa-eye' ></i>
                    </button>";

                    echo
```